# clang compile c++ to wasm , stdio.h not found error occurs

Tags: clang, webassembly

I typed：

```
 clang -emit-llvm --target=wasm32 -Oz my.cpp -c -o math.bc
```

There have always been the following errors:

```
my.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
```

my source as following:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"

void ttt()
{
        double ww = pow((double)2.0, (double)0.3);
        print(ww);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing a libc, or at least not pointing you compiler at one.  If you use `emscripten` or `wasi-sdk` they ship with a libc.   Noramlly if you run clang directly you need to pass `--sysroot=` to point it at your libc.